# Add padding for SpanElement with background color

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a Spark TextArea with a SpanElement inside. This element has the backgroundColor property set, but I would like to have the background a bit taller because it looks a bit weird at the top like this.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohl0F.png

I already tried to adjust lineHeight and paddingTop for the SpanElement, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Which TLF version you used? 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with backgroundColor in text span you can tweak the baselineShift to change the relative position of the text and background.
FTQuest

Comment: Setting the baselineShift to a negative value makes it slightly better, but unfortunately the text is positioned lower than other SpanElements in the paragraph then. Is there any workaround for this?